# Retrieve contacts from a set of phone numbers

Tags: android, contactscontract

I wish to retrieve Contacts list based on a set of phone numbers. What is going wrong here?

Currently using this -

```
private String numbers = "'12345', '54321'";

String[] mSelectionArgs = {numbers};'

return new CursorLoader(getActivity(),
                    PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI,
                    ContactsQuery.PROJECTION,
                    ContactsQuery.SELECTION,
                    mSelectionArgs,
                    PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME);
```

PROJECTION and SELECTION are defined in ContactsQuery as follows

```
final static String[] PROJECTION = {
        PhoneLookup._ID,

        PhoneLookup.LOOKUP_KEY,

            PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME,

            PhoneLookup.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI,

    };

final static String SELECTION =     
            PhoneLookup.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + "=1 AND " + PhoneLookup.NUMBER) + " IN (?)";
```

However, I get the error:

07-08 00:44:21.007: E/AndroidRuntime(2307): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI: content://com.android.contacts/phone_lookup, calling user: com.example.android.contactslist, calling package:com.example.android.contactslist

Answer (score 0):

Try:

ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, (DISPLAY_NAME = '" + name + "'"), null, null);

Comment: Contacts.CONTENT_URI will not allow me to filter based on PhoneNumbers. Hence the usage of PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI